# How can I prevent a VirtualBox guest .vdi from getting released when I restart the host?

Tags: virtualbox

I'm using VirtualBox. My host and guest machines are both running Ubuntu. Every time I restart the host computer, one of my virtual machines becomes corrupted (the guest `.vdi` gets released).

I've found that opening the Virtual Media Manager and dragging the `.vdi` file for the corrupted machine into it makes everything go back to normal. However, this is a nuisance, and having to do it every time isn't ideal.

I get the same result whether I shut down or save the state of the guest. I always shut down or save the guest before I shut down, suspend or hibernate the host.

How can I make the `.vdi` stop this behavior and stay connected to the virtual machine?

Comment: What is your host operating system?  Do you shut down the VM before shutting down the host?

Comment: I made an edit to the original. thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Very strange.  Might be something is wrong in the VirtualBox.xml file.  Try making another virtual machine with identical virtual hardware characteristics, but specify the existing vdi instead of creating a new virtual disk (and of course, back up the vdi before doing so).

Answer (score 0):

Add "SHUTDOWN=savestate" to /etc/default/virtualbox on the host. 
When "/etc/init.d/vboxdrv stop" gets run durring shutdown, all the VMs will be saved.